# Regular Expression for Phone Number and excludes decimal numbers

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I use this regex to recognize phone numbers in my app.  "\\+?\\d{7,23}"
But this cannot exclude decimal numbers like 3.1415926。

How to modify this regex, so that it can recognize phone numbers and do not give me decimal numbers like 3.1415926, 99.9999999。

In this case, the '1415926' and '9999999' will be recognized as phone number, which is not desired.

In a word, I want to reject numbers with '.' to be partially recognized as phone number. Or a phone number should not be succeeded with '.' or follow '.'.

Thanks.

Finally, I solved this problem using [image]

Comment: Do you want to accept or reject numbers such as `3.14159`?  This is not clear from the wording on your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to reject numbers with '.' to be partially recognized as phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^\+?((?!\.)\d){7,23}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
\+                string starts with an optional +
((?!\.)\d){7,23}  negative lookahead asserts that string contains between 7 and 23
                  numbers, each of which is not a dot
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Hi, with '^' and '&' this regex is used to test if a whole text matches phone number. But I need to use this regex to extract all phone numbers from arbitrary text. I removed '^' and '$', and used "3.1415926，0.0000001%，99.999999%, 2352352352.553535454.54545455" to test the regex, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the flavor of regex you are using, or the application, but you could try `.*\+?((?!\.)\d){7,23}.*` which would match the pattern anywhere in the string, possibly multiple times.